unget or similar solution for boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream
I want to read binary messages from a boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream and I have therefore overloaded the >> operator with istream &operator>>(istream &stream, Message &message) so I can read messages with stream >> message which works fine.
Due to the characteristics of the incoming binary data, it can happen that the synchronization process has to be restarted after having already read half the message. If a fstream would be used one could simply put_back or unget the characters that have to be read again. Unfortunately put_back, unget or seekg won't work for boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream. A peek of multiple bytes would also do the trick.
I found this open SO post from 2010 and this open SO post from 2018 which were of no help.
I realize there is no way to put back bytes into that tcp stream. How would one implement a buffer that accomplishes that in a modern c++ way ?

Use a std::vector and store the bytes in that until there is enough to extract a message

well, the issue is not having enough bytes available. The issue is that it only seemed that there was a message but its not. In that case one has to restart the search inside the already read bytes.

I don't see the problem. You continue to put data in the vector until you find something identifiable and discard what you can't use. You may want to put some examples of broken data streams in the question. Btw, since it's a TCP stream, wouldn't it be better to discard the broken data before sending it?

true! But i want to avoid the extra copy and read directly into the destination. It would be nice if the sender would only send valid messages but I don't have control over it. Is it possible to pipe the tcp stream in another istream that supports unget or create a vector from the istream that buffers the bytes I put back?

@JoKing just use a view into the original buffer with std::string_view or std::span, no need to do any copy

@phuclv what original buffer? There is only the boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream

I'd use a composed read operation with a completion condition. Implement the completion condition to detect partial vs complete messages. E.g. to read length-prefixed binary data:
template <typename Buffer, typename SyncReadStream, typename CompletionToken>
static auto async_read_message(SyncReadStream& s, Buffer&& buf, Message& message, CompletionToken&& token) {
    return asio::async_read(
        s, buf,
        [&](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t /*n*/) -> size_t {
            size_t expect = 0;
            if (!ec.failed()) {
                auto              data = buf.data();
                std::vector<char> raw(asio::buffers_begin(data), asio::buffers_end(data));

                expect = raw.size() < 4 //
                    ? 4 - raw.size()    // need more header
                    : message.require_more(raw);
            }
            // std::cout << "condition " << ec.message() << " -> " << expect << std::endl;
            return expect;
        },
        std::forward<CompletionToken>(token));
}

We encode the parsing inside the Message type:
struct Message {
    std::vector<char> data;

    // Test whether buf contains valid, complete message; returns 0 if complete, or the number of bytes
    // required
    static size_t require_more(std::span<char const> buf) {
        assert(buf.size() >= 4);          // at least the header
        size_t len = extract_length(buf); // incomplete header, read more

        auto payload = buf.subspan(4);
        return len - std::min(len, payload.size()); // 0 if complete
    }

    size_t parse(std::span<char const> buf) {
        auto len = extract_length(buf);
        assert(buf.size() >= 4 + len);

        auto payload = buf.subspan(4, len);
        data.assign(payload.begin(), payload.end());
        return 4 + len;
    }

  private:
    static size_t extract_length(std::span<char const> header) {
        assert(header.size() >= 4); // at least the header

        uint32_t len{};
        std::memcpy(&len, header.data(), 4);

        if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::little)
            len = std::byteswap(len); // big-endian on the wire

        return len;
    }
};


Note the attention to network byte ordering

Live Demo
Putting it together with a server
asio::awaitable<void> server() {
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(co_await asio::this_coro::executor, {tcp::v4(), 5555});
    tcp::socket   s = co_await acceptor.async_accept();

    using namespace std::string_view_literals;
    asio::streambuf buf;

    // preseed the buffer with a few messages, to witness the buffering working
    std::ostream(&buf) << "\0\0\0\x01"sv << "a"                   // 1
                       << "\0\0\0\x2a"sv << std::string(42, 'a'); // 42

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    for (; !ec;) {
        Message message;
        auto    n = co_await async_read_message( //
            s, buf, message, redirect_error(asio::deferred, ec));

        if (!ec) {
            auto              data = buf.data();
            std::vector<char> raw(asio::buffers_begin(data), asio::buffers_end(data));
            buf.consume(message.parse(raw));
            std::cout << "Received message payload of " << message.data.size() << " bytes"
                      << " (transferred: " << n << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Server done (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
}

And a client that sends 4 additional messages:
asio::awaitable<void> client() {
    tcp::socket s(co_await asio::this_coro::executor);
    co_await s.async_connect({{}, 5555});

    for (int i : {0, 3, 42, 1}) {
        Message message{std::vector<char>(i, 'z')};

        uint32_t len = message.data.size();
        if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::little)
            len = std::byteswap(len); // big-endian on the wire

        co_await asio::async_write(s,
                                   std::array{
                                       asio::buffer(&len, 4),
                                       asio::buffer(message.data),
                                   });
        std::cout << "Sent message payload of " << message.data.size() << " bytes" << std::endl;
    }
}

Live On Compiler Explorer
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
static_assert(std::endian::native == std::endian::big ||
              std::endian::native == std::endian::little); // mixed endian not supported

struct Message {
    std::vector<char> data;

    // Test whether buf contains valid, complete message; returns 0 if complete, or the number of bytes
    // required
    static size_t require_more(std::span<char const> buf) {
        assert(buf.size() >= 4);          // at least the header
        size_t len = extract_length(buf); // incomplete header, read more

        auto payload = buf.subspan(4);
        return len - std::min(len, payload.size()); // 0 if complete
    }

    size_t parse(std::span<char const> buf) {
        auto len = extract_length(buf);
        assert(buf.size() >= 4 + len);

        auto payload = buf.subspan(4, len);
        data.assign(payload.begin(), payload.end());
        return 4 + len;
    }

  private:
    static size_t extract_length(std::span<char const> header) {
        assert(header.size() >= 4); // at least the header

        uint32_t len{};
        std::memcpy(&len, header.data(), 4);

        if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::little)
            len = std::byteswap(len); // big-endian on the wire

        return len;
    }
};

template <typename Buffer, typename SyncReadStream, typename CompletionToken>
static auto async_read_message(SyncReadStream& s, Buffer&& buf, Message& message, CompletionToken&& token) {
    return asio::async_read(
        s, buf,
        [&](boost::system::error_code ec, size_t /*n*/) -> size_t {
            size_t expect = 0;
            if (!ec.failed()) {
                auto              data = buf.data();
                std::vector<char> raw(asio::buffers_begin(data), asio::buffers_end(data));

                expect = raw.size() < 4 //
                    ? 4 - raw.size()    // need more header
                    : message.require_more(raw);
            }
            // std::cout << "condition " << ec.message() << " -> " << expect << std::endl;
            return expect;
        },
        std::forward<CompletionToken>(token));
}

asio::awaitable<void> server() {
    tcp::acceptor acceptor(co_await asio::this_coro::executor, {tcp::v4(), 5555});
    tcp::socket   s = co_await acceptor.async_accept();

    using namespace std::string_view_literals;
    asio::streambuf buf;

    // preseed the buffer with a few messages, to witness the buffering working
    std::ostream(&buf) << "\0\0\0\x01"sv << "a"                   // 1
                       << "\0\0\0\x2a"sv << std::string(42, 'a'); // 42

    boost::system::error_code ec;
    for (; !ec;) {
        Message message;
        auto    n = co_await async_read_message( //
            s, buf, message, redirect_error(asio::deferred, ec));

        if (!ec) {
            auto              data = buf.data();
            std::vector<char> raw(asio::buffers_begin(data), asio::buffers_end(data));
            buf.consume(message.parse(raw));
            std::cout << "Received message payload of " << message.data.size() << " bytes"
                      << " (transferred: " << n << ")" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "Server done (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
}

asio::awaitable<void> client() {
    tcp::socket s(co_await asio::this_coro::executor);
    co_await s.async_connect({{}, 5555});

    for (int i : {0, 3, 42, 1}) {
        Message message{std::vector<char>(i, 'z')};

        uint32_t len = message.data.size();
        if constexpr (std::endian::native == std::endian::little)
            len = std::byteswap(len); // big-endian on the wire

        co_await asio::async_write(s,
                                   std::array{
                                       asio::buffer(&len, 4),
                                       asio::buffer(message.data),
                                   });
        std::cout << "Sent message payload of " << message.data.size() << " bytes" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context io_context;

    co_spawn(io_context, server(), asio::detached);
    co_spawn(io_context, client(), asio::detached);

    io_context.run();
}

Prints
Received message payload of 1 bytes (transferred: 0)
Sent message payload of 0 bytes
Received message payload of 42 bytes (transferred: 0)
Sent message payload of 3 bytes
Received message payload of 0 bytes (transferred: 4)
Sent message payload of 42 bytes
Sent message payload of 1 bytes
Received message payload of 3 bytes (transferred: 7)
Received message payload of 42 bytes (transferred: 46)
Received message payload of 1 bytes (transferred: 5)
Server done (End of file)


Other Links
A similar example can be seen in an older answer of mine: boost::asio::async_read_until with custom match_char to accept only JSON format

wow, give me a day to understand this o.o

Look, I had to make up details to be able to demonstrate. This specific task could be a LOT simpler (e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/qWGo75vve). If you show me actual problem code I could perhaps suggest you a more elegant solution.
